# как установить связь между объектами?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, relation

```
public class master
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public virtual ObservableCollection<detail> det { get; set; }
    public master()
    {
        det = new ObservableCollection<detail>();
    }
}
public class detail : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    private int _id_master;
    public int id_master
    {
        get { return _id_master; }
        set { _id_master = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private master _mast;
    public virtual master mast
    {
        get { return _mast; }
        set { _mast = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }


}
public class PropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

устанавливаю связь между мастером и деталью 1:М

```
        DbModelBuilder mb = new DbModelBuilder();
        mb.Entity<Master>()
            .HasKey(pk => pk.Id)
            .HasMany<detail>(a => a.Det)
            .WithOptional(o => o.Mast);

        mb.Entity<Detail>()
            .HasRequired(r => r.Mast)
            .WithMany(m => m.Det)
            .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.Id_master);
```

далее создаю объект мастера и делали

```
Master mm = new Master() { Id = 1 };
Detail dd = new Detail() { Id = 10, Id_master = 1 };
```

и как бы полагаю, что теперь в окне контрольных значений увижу, что mm.Det - заполнен, а чуда не произошло (
Как сделать так, чтобы C# понял, что эти 2 объекта связаны между собой? (не прибегая к записи вида mm.det.Add(dd);

**UPD**
и ещё:

```
detail dd1 = new detail() { id = 11 };
mm.det.Add(dd1);
```

не выставляет автоматом id_master=1 (

Comment: а Вы каким то образом информируете `Master` о том что у нее изменилась вложенная коллекция?

Comment: пока нет селекта к базе вы не сможете увидеть значения в дочерней коллекции.

Comment: @Bald56rus есть только этот код. C INotifyChanged вроде тоже не получалось увидеть %)

Comment: смотрите как только Вы добавляете новую запись в `Detail` Вы должны *уведомить* соответствующую запись в `Master` которая подтянет новые строки для себя. это если не вдаваясь в подробности, а лучше опишите что Вы хотите сделать, а то возникают сомнения в связи с Вашим комментарием под ответом

Comment: обновил вопрос: добавил вызов NotifyPropertyChanged(). Пока не получается увидеть в mm заполненный det. Хочется составить старую-добрую реляцию. Временно) Между объектами в памяти.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы работаете в памяти - забудьте вообще про такую вещь как EF и Id. Они не предназначены для этого.

```
Master mm = new Master { };
Detail dd = new Detail { master = mm };
mm.Details.Add(dd);
```

Если стоит задача избавиться от последнего вызова - можно попробовать так:

```
// В классе Detail
private Master _master;
public virtual Master Master
{
    get { return _master; }
    set {
      if (_master == value) return;
      if (_master != null && _master.Details != null)
        _master.Details.Remove(detail);
      _master = value;
      if (_master != null && _master.Details != null)
        _master.Details.Add(detail);
    }
}
```

В принципе, EF тоже может помочь с этой задачей - но там полно тонкостей:

```
Master mm = new Master { };
ctx.Masters.Add(mm);
Detail dd = new Detail { master = mm };
ctx.Details.Add(mm);
```

теперь обратная связь появилась автоматически. Но тут нужен контекст - и, опять-таки, нельзя использовать Id. Кроме того, обновляются связи в EF в довольно неожиданные моменты времени.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения. Только объясните - зачем существуют в mb.Entity<Master>() всякие .Has*(), .With*() и т.п? Я натурально не понимаю почему нет реляций без контекстов? Чтоли всегда нужно в модель лезть, добавлять эти связи в конструкторе EDMX? О_о. В ВинФормс вытянул ДатаСеты, поставил реляции и всё пучком. А здесь про такой подход вообще забыть?

Comment: @HellRiser потому что EntityFramework - это ORM. Библиотека для отображения объектной модели на реляционную базу данных. Логично, что она не работает без базы данных!

Comment: @HellRiser кстати, вы уже 2й раз упоминаете конструктор EDMX. Зачем вы к нему прицепились?

Comment: потому что только в нём указаны связи )

Comment: @HellRiser при подходе ModelFirst - да. Но есть же еще CodeFirst и DatabaseFirst...

Comment: ок. модель DF. С сервера вытянута модель. но в MS SQL, например, между представлениями нет связей. Но мне они нужны, чтобы получить правильный отчёт. Вытянув данные из двух представлений мне нужно их связать. Ибо тупое проставление в .Any()  или в конструкции foreach отнимает дохреналиард времени. Я думал, надеялся, что связь как-то разгрузит подкачку данных. Всё оказывается не так?

Comment: @HellRiser тогда зачем вы задали вопрос про заполнение объектов вручную - если вы их на самом деле из БД вытягиваете?!

Comment: @HellRiser если у вас данные и правда вытягиваются из БД - да, вам надо просто добавить связь в EDMX, отключить инициализацию контекста - и все заработает.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае алгоритм будет следующим: вам надо создать объект зависимой модели - в данном случае модели detail, присвоить ее свойству id_master идентификатор мастер и добавить этот объект в базу данных с помощью методов Add у соответствующего набора данных и метода контекста SaveChanges.
По данному вопросу могу порекомендовать посмотреть следующий пример http://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.7.php

Comment: реляция работает только с базами банных? мне нужно просто связать 2 объекта, которые находятся в памяти. В EDMX я ничего не рисовал. Есть только представленный код